# Hover tags ain't working

Tags: css, tags, hover, themes, tumblr

I've got a question for this theme here: http://minewt.tk/post/130142745774/theme-29-persephone-20-preview-download-a . The tags in this theme don't show, and I already know how to fix that (removing the `{block:permalinkpage}` in the html before the `{block:tags}`), and I know how to make hover tags (add `opacity:0;` in the css and

```
#post:hover .tags {
opacity:1;
-moz-transition:all 0.8s;
-ms-transition:all 0.8s;
-o-transition:all 0.8s;
transition:all 0.8s;  
}
```

right after it, but the problem with this theme is that the css for the tags looks like this:

```
.indexed {
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}

.tag {
text-transform:uppercase;
color:{color:link};
font-size:8px;
letter-spacing:.5px;
}
.tags {
font-size:9px;
letter-spacing:0px;
transition:0.4s ease-in;
-webkit-transition:0.4s ease-in;
-moz-transition:0.4s ease-in;
}


.tags a {
border:none;
margin-right:3px;
}
```

I've tried putting the #post:hover everywhere, but the tags still remain invisible (when I put `opacity:0;`in both the .tag and .tags css). Can anyone help, or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Can you link to an example? This should be straighforward, but your code is somewhat incomplete. #post should be unique on the page as it is an id. So it might need an update to your markup.

Comment: Well as I said it is difficult to tell exactly without seeing some of your html markup, but I have made this jsfiddle for you. See if this is behaving how you would like, if not then at least you can elaborate and other people can edit and change the jsfiddle code. https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/440c5x43/ Incidentally this has more than one occurrence of the #post tag (id) which you should not really have is it is not valid markup. I would change this to .post (class name).

Comment: I am going to downvote this question.